# When using @azure/Msal-browser, I get this error message on ClientAuthError: state_not_found: State not found

Tags: typescript, azure, create-react-app, azure-ad-msal

I'm developing an using @azure/msal-browser on `http://localhost` using `create-react-app`, when trying to login via `msal.loginRedirect()` the browser retuns to the site, and correct page however the user is not logged in and the following error is in the console (from the *handleRedirectPromise* method)
`ClientAuthError: state_not_found: State not found:  Cached State`

A state parameter *is* passed into the login url (https://login.microsoft.com...state=**base64string**...) but nothing is in the Local/Session/Cookie storage.

The Azure app config is fine (having being used before), something is not wokring/configured with the msal library, any ideas?

Comment: Which MSAL version and code flow you are using?

Answer (score 4):

This error can be caused if the handleRedirectPromise is called twice. msal-react should call this function for you, so there is no need to do this call yourself. See this github issue for more information: [msal-browser redirect not working correctly](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/2796).

Comment: thank you this answered saved me big time.

Comment: glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

I got this error in NextJS app when wrap the MSAL Provider with top level logger context. The issue was in `useEffect` usage inside logger context - it was making an incorrect rendering order, and because of this the page was crushing with errors `state_not_found` or `no_cached_authority_error` - was depends of my MSAL module codebase. Hope it may help for some one.